# Xcode 4.2 Interface Builder Dock Icons

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I've been trying to complete some basic tutorials to familiarize myself with UIViews and ViewControllers, but some tutorials I see ask me to select an "*app name* App Delegate" icon in the dock (just left of the Interface Builder panel).  I'm seeing the icons for Placeholders: "File's Owner", "File's Responder" and icons for the Objects I've added to my view, but no icon for an App Delegate.

This is using an iOS Empty Application and not any other template when creating a new project and I'm basically trying to connect my App Delegate's rootViewController outlet to a view Controller in a nib file.

Has this icon been removed from XCode 4.2?  Is it somewhere else or can be accessed in a different way? I'm guessing a lot of my confusion is because I'm referencing tutorials that came before XCode 4.2 and the new iOS 5 SDK.  I'm really new to XCode and iOS in general and the lack of up to date tutorials is not helping my confusion.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The default Xcode 4.2 templates no longer have the app delegate created by the xib. Instead, the class name is passed into `UIApplicationMain` so that can instantiate it. This change was made as part of Storyboard support, as I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost positive that I've had the same problem, but I figured out that for whatever reason, it would only accept the icon in png format. Try that and see if it works. If this answer is completely off topic, blame that on my lack of sleep for the past 36 hours.